# How to solve NK?

Tags: warfare, strategy, invasion, nuclear-war

**How to solve NK?**

NK is developing a nuclear missile program that might target sooner or later, various states in the world. As a result, there could be casualties ranging from thousands to millions of people. And generally any attempt to attack NK in a bad way may lead to turning the state of SK into a desert.

To avoid this situation, NK's nuclear missile program needs to be shut down, be it through physical dismantling or through negotiations or some form of them, that would lead the leader to quit the development of the missile program.
The writer does not like war, warfare, and any kind of deadly violence.
Therefore, the writer would like that, if wars happen, to be solved through non-lethal weapons and capturing of enemy soldiers and re-educating them.

For the purpose of this question, NK would be the fictitious state of North Koreistan and SK would be the fictitious state of South Koreistan.

The answers the writer of this question is looking for is stopping NK's missile program with minimum to no casualties.

The writer has it's own version for an answer, and would like to hear more opinions.

Comment: It's pretty obvious you are trying to be off topic.

Comment: Worldbuilding SE is the wrong venue to discuss existing, real-world geopolitical issues.

Comment: Am thinking to go to a different community with the same question, thank you @Frostfyre

Comment: The question is more apropriate in a discussion forum. Stack exchange can't help since nobody knows the answer, we may just speculate.

Comment: Any suggestions for a discussion forum?

Comment: Suggestions for third-party resources are also off-topic.

Comment: @Steve-O Not even politics stack exchange? Source please for your assertion?

Comment: @a4android thankfully, there is politics and posted it there too. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: @JustW I hope you have better luck there. We should try to be helpful. If there are other resources, why not tell people about them? An expert on NK suggested information warfare. Let NK people know about the outside world & what they're missing, to eventually foster a revolution in the political elite. Hopefully the new government will be less belligerent.

Comment: Thank you @a4android. The idea of letting NK people about the outside world could be done via SK. After all, lots of electronics (think Samsung) and even tv shows are done in that place. In a way, SK is leading the way.

Answer (score 1):

Normal diplomacy won't work with the dictator of NK, whose people revere him as a god-king.  The only long-term way of dealing with it is regime change.

**Isolation**

Cut off NK from all other nations.  This deprives it of the resources it needs in order to continue its missile program while increasing the pressure on the regime from within and without.

**Project Strength**

The brutal dictator must know that aggression will be met in kind, preferably by drastic, overwhelming force (You punch me, I shoot you, and burn down your house.)  This will help him moderate his impulses.  You launch a single missile, your country will be a glowing wasteland.

**Undermine His Rule**

Send covert operatives across the border, smuggling food, medicine, radios, portable TVs and books.  Spend lots of money broadcasting Radio-free NK, with propaganda extolling the benefits of the free society of SK.  TV is broadcast to the starving NK people showing the abundant and cheap food of SK.

**The Real Solution**

All of the above won't work.  The ruler won't leave his throne unless pried out by violence or the threat thereof.  It has been this way throughout history.  Without taking direct action, you can only slow him down.  The ruler sees a strong nuclear deterrent as the key to getting everything he wants because nobody threatens a state with the bomb.

The most non-violent way to dispose of a dictator is to remove the dictator.  A coup would work, but that is bloody, expensive, difficult, and hard to control.  Direct military involvement is also bloody, expensive, and hard to limit.  Bombing facilities risk escalating the conflict into a shooting conflict.

Seal Team Six breaking into the leader's bedroom one night, however, could easily solve the problem.  With the leader removed (whether removed means from power or from life), the current regime would topple (dear leader executed anyone who could possibly lead in his place.  Dictators don't last long if they aren't proactive like that.)

Comment: Appreciate your solution. The question is how to do it while minimizing casualties.

Answer (score -2):

The writer, thus, decided to write a solution to this problem, using specific steps, that, would make the NK leader lose face and respect from anybody, if any violent steps from him are taken.

The solution is to simply propose NK to renounce it's nuclear missile program and to open it's borders, in exchange for foreign investment and improving the lives of NK people.
But, due to expected NK dictatorship nature, this will probably never work, and thus any country/state that wants to solve NK, has to prove it to the NK leadership and it's people, that they want to help.
As a result, the best choice is to build shelters with food, clothing and education to integrate any fleeing people of NK. For this article, the state that will be involved in solving NK problem, will simply be called 'The State', or 'State'.
The State, after building shelters across the border of NK, will first attempt through bribes, maybe infiltration or simply, promotions(publicity), that it would be good if NK defending soldiers would simply join a better life in the shelters, with food and possibly work to do.
If that does not work, then The State will have no choice but to shoot the stubborn soldiers with rubber bullets or any other type of non-lethal deadly weapons, as to immobilize them, then capture them, and send them to prison camps where they either face a lonely cell with food once every 48 hours, or choose to re-educate themselves and reintegrate with working people. This will open the NK borders, get the NK people out and as a result, the borders would slowly fade away, as shelters continue to advance in NK. Of course, any missile strikes need to be stopped with defensive missiles.
The only reason, the pre-emptive uses of solving the problem, even if they would likely not work, is to show the world and the people of NK that the leadership is not looking for a peaceful solution and will probably never will and that, The State, is the good guy, and NK is the bad guy.
When NK loses face and looks like the bad guy, any remaining leadership would attempt to flee, and thus NK would be left with low morale people with nothing to defend.

Now, for the actual steps:

1. Create shelters with food, clothing and educational facilities across the border with SK; Also create employment opportunities from the people that are refugees out there.
   The employment opportunities can vary from any kind of self-sustainability projects, that produce food. See aquaponics for example. These people will be educated and provided to produce food for themselves and of course, have a market where they can sell the food to.
   Creating factories that can make clothing there is also a great idea...
   Also create shelters or settlements that are similar to housing, and can be easily upgraded by themselves into housing.
   Also, before putting any shelters, make sure the borders are protected with all kinds of equipment as to make sure there are no rockets launched that could damage the shelters or equipment that can intercept missiles in mid-air before rockets shoot, as to protect SK and it's borders.
2. Open borders from SK. Shoot any NK soldiers who are attacking with non-lethal force. Capture them after they are immobilized then transfer them to prisons where they can choose either to re-educate themselves with materials provided at prisons to reintegrate into their new lives or they can choose to sit into a dark room, with close to no sunlight, only air and water, and food every 24 to 48 hours.
3. Encourage any military and citizens from NK to join them in SK, to work there, instead of serve in the military. After all, they are 5-10 miles away from freedom...
4. Soldiers and refugees, being encouraged to build housing for themselves and actually having the materials, will make the easiest conquest, because, slowly, the borders will be left empty, and, slowly, NK establishment will be left with no people to defend the dictator.
   The plan is to simply not be agressive against their military using lethal force. Just use rubber bullets or any other kind of solution.
   Somehow inform people of NK they will leave the country unharmed and be free from NK dictatorship.
   Doing all the above...
   People of NK will be unharmed and saved.
   There will be no battles that involve many casualties.
   And of course, whomever decides to use this plan against NK, will probably get the utmost respect, be it any country that is neighbor by land or sea.
   Of course, this plan is based on soldiers abandoning their military outposts.
   If this doesn't work, then an invasion of troops with non-lethal weapons to  immobilize the defenders will still work, but requires overwhelming firepower, especially rapid firepower.
   Use rubber bullets or something else that can stun, immobilize, but not kill or permanently paralyze. An addition would be automatic machine gun with very high rate of fire, supplied with non-lethal rubber bullets. Working on the principle, even though bullets are not deadly, but if they are many, troops could not avoid them. However it needs a lot of amno and high firepower rate.
   Continue to promote a good life in SK, with good shelters across the borders and of course the promise of seeing their own homeland after moving slowly but surely the borders closer and closer.
   Slowly but surely NK will lose all it's support.
   Also, for the military that is stubborn, they will be kept as prisoners, with food once every 24 to 48 hours. Alone, each in their own cell, with the choice to be re-educated...
   They will give up. No torture allowed, no beatings allowed.
   Starvation will slowly but surely make them change their mind.
   Whomever succeeds with this solution will be granted the benefit, of having poor citizens to ask rich foreign countries to 'invade them'. Just imagine the people from the fictitious state of Venezuelistan saying "Invade us!", or "Invade the government of ... " or "Help us from the tyranny of ... ".

A short summary:

- Promote an economic investment in NK, in exchange for NK renouncing it's nukes and having open borders
- If that fails(likely), then go for building shelters with food and resources and create factories around the borders of NK.
  Create incentives so that people of NK would want to flee and work across the border for better conditions.
- If no one is allowed to go open the border(which is the current situation), then somehow encourage soldiers to join the work camps for a better life. With better work, etc.
- If that does not work, then use rubber bullets or any kind of non lethal stuff and get the soldiers of NK off their borders, so that people of NK can flee and get into refugee shelters and build themselves a new life.
  At this point NK people would flee from the borders.
  Of course, another set of borders, between the NK borders and refugees would be set, as to not create a situation where NK troops would instead invade.

The plan is to simply build infrastructure as if NK is not really a threat, have good security to protect that infrastructure and somehow make the people of NK go work into that great infrastructure built by The State.
This plan requires investments in factories of clothing and food. It obviously can create a lot of profit off the cheap labor out there. And with self-sustainable agriculture, the people there will very likely not be short of supplies.
It is somewhat expected that, after some time, and the investments done across NK borders, the leader will cease it's missile program and lose it's ambition. When he sees that it's own people will be helped by the so called 'enemy' as he calls it, then he would have no choice but to concede and resign, because the alternative is to continuously lie to it's people about how great it's country is and how good the infrastructure would be.

This would be a battle won through investments, that would be paying off due to cheap labor.
It can be implemented now, for the next 20 years. Because if not, a point of no return will be reached, where there will be literally no use for the people when robots will do the labor more cheaply, and then... this 'investment opportunity' won't be as attractive.
The State, whomever it will be, will likely be seen in a great image, who won, not even needing to fight a battle.
NK thus becomes a good emerging economy, well integrated, with cheap labor.
So now, who will take the opportunity, to become 'The State' ?

Comment: No, no, no I can't read this. Second paragraph and you are already making a massive mistake that invalidates your argument. You assume that by attempting to send aid we would seem morally superior to the NK public. However the NK public would not know about this! They don't have the internet. Their news tells them America is evil no matter what actually happens. . . Okay I glanced at it again, open borders? Again the borders are closed from the inside, the reason people don't leave is because the NK government will kill them if they try to, not because we barricade them in.

Comment: Go to politics stack exchange and read the [NK questions.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-korea) There is a lot of information there to read. If these questions don't explain why your solution is broken, you can ask more questions on politics.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @Braydon. As it is seen, it takes things step by step, the main focus of the story is shelters, not whether the people there have internet or not. A better life opportunity and rumors can somewhat change outcomes. Also it is known that people are kept in borders, and in the solution, the first step is to convince the military guarding it to stand down, and later on to immobilize them if they do not comply.

Comment: But what reason would the military stand down for? The military is keeping people trapped in NK in order to maintain their control. What incentive could you give them to surrender that control?

Comment: @Braydon Better food, shelters, clothing, technology, 5 miles away from them. And of course freedom from the mighty dictatorship. Also showing off the wealth might have a good effect. And if they do not leave,they are shot down with rubber bullets from miles away, for not leaving the outposts. Surely that can make them angry, but they can be threatened that if they don't comply, real bullets may be used instead. And they can be hit anytime. Death and dictatorship or comfortable life outside the outpost?

Comment: There is so much wrong about this answer I don't even know where to start. Assuming the NK artillery won't retaliate against abducting their people by flattening Seoul? The claim that slowly starving people to death is not torture? That you can actually win a military engagement against armed people when you are restricted to non-lethal weapons without massive own casualties? Assuming rubber bullets are just harmless stun rounds which won't kill people if they hit them wrong? That you can just "reeducate" people? There is so much more, but I am running out of characters.

Comment: @Philipp I'm fixed with a correct model based on re-education. Also it is clearly mentioned there that an anti missile defence would be put in place to make sure any attempt of hitting sensitive areas is avoided. And for firepower, automatic un-manned machine guns, with high rate of power would be able to minimize any casualties from the other side.

Comment: @JustW The NK artillery threatening Seoul aren't missiles. They are conventional mortars. There is no known active defense system against mortar shells. And autonomous weapon system operating on the ground are still science fiction. Especially any which are able to capture opponents alive.

Comment: @Philipp Agree with the mortar argument. If mortars would attempt to strike then there is no other choice but to bomb the mortars to avoid any major casualties done to SK. Recently learned there is a 30km range at the border filled with mortars. As for autonomous shooting system with intervention either programmed or with the operator in a remote location, that can be done, but no capturing opponents. The idea would be if the autonomous machine guns would level the opponents up, but considering mortars, there is not much of a choice except destroy the artillery first.

Comment: There is however the solution to use non-lethal gas, but uncertain about the variables, and how effective. A gas that puts people to sleep across the border would most likely render the artillery useless and the people at the borders. As for capturing the prisoners afterwards, it would not be easy.

Comment: Most likely, the most effective way would be close to instant attack on all levels before the opponent would lift a finger. Synced attack with gas to render troops immobilized, while at the same time disabling any kind of projectiles. It's something, probably very hard to do and not my area of expertise. The only reason I posted the idea is because  "shelters at the borders" and some sort of investment opportunity. Solving it diplomatically with promise of investments in exchange for more open borders in the future and renouncing military capabilities would be best, but will it ever go there?